# Retrieve commits from phabricator

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I am using arcanist for phabricator. For some of my commits I had done an `arc diff` but had not yet pushed to the remote repository. Because of some weird reason I lost my local `.git` folder. Is it possible to get my commits from phabricator?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you had submitted your work for review, by running `arc diff`, it's just a matter of requesting that review from phabricator. You do that by running `arc patch Dxxx`, with `Dxxx` replaced by the differential number of your review request.